# How to get a list of sessions connected to the DB over links?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to get a list of sessions connected to the database by links?

I need to change schema owner password, and I assume that there may be some database links that connect to my database with this username / password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have auditing enabled in the database, and you're auditing sessions (connections) via "AUDIT SESSION;", then you can get some info from the audit trail, like so.

```
Select * from dba_common_audit_trail where comment_text like 'DBLINK_INFO:%';
```

Example: This will give you the source host name and database name, specifically for connections that were established over a database link.

```
Select 
   userhost, 
   statement_type as type, 
   comment_text 
from dba_common_audit_trail 
where comment_text like 'DBLINK_INFO:%';
```

---

```
USERHOST            TYPE    COMMENT_TEXT
somehostname        LOGOFF  DBLINK_INFO: (SOURCE_GLOBAL_NAME=SOMEDB.11157502)
somehostname        LOGOFF  DBLINK_INFO: (SOURCE_GLOBAL_NAME=SOMEDB.11157504)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the current open sessions in the session table. If you did not close the link forcibly. `alter session close database link <db_link>`.

```
select username , machine,program,logon_time  from v$session
where type='USER'
and program like 'oracle@%'


USERNAME              MACHINE                       PROGRAM                LOGON_TIME               
---------------- ----------------------- ----------------------------- ---------------- 
MANAGER               esmd                  oracle@esmd (TNS V1-V3)    21-08-2019 08:28:36
```

All connections (completed and open now) you can see in the listener log.

```
[oracle@db-01 trace]$ tail -100 listener.log |grep 'PROGRAM=oracle'
21-AUG-2019 08:28:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)(CID=(PROGRAM=oracle)(HOST=xxxxxx)(USER=DeminDV))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx.xx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=29767)) * establish * edcu * 0
21-AUG-2019 08:28:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)(CID=(PROGRAM=oracle)(HOST=xxxxxx)(USER=DeminDV))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx.xx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=29770)) * establish * edcu * 0
```